# is it possible to use w32codecs on a 64bit system?

Tags: linux, 64bit, mplayer

Is there any chance I can load binary codecs on 64bit arch linux ? I have few .dat files that works great under 32bit windows xp, with smplayer (after downloading codecs), but on 64bit Linux, I got twisted image.

I downloaded all binary codecs [for win32 here](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/codecs/all-20110131.tar.bz2),

And essential e[lf64 libs here](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/codecs/essential-amd64-20071007.tar.bz2)

Both archive was extracted to `/usr/lib/codecs`

From output of strace, seems `/usr/lib/codecs` wasn't loaded.

P.S attached mplayer log

```
MPlayer SVN-r35014-4.7.1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
195 audio & 404 video codecs
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing avseq03.dat.
libavformat version 54.15.100 (internal)
MPEG-PS file format detected.
VIDEO:  MPEG1  352x288  (aspect 8)  25.000 fps  1120.0 kbps (140.0 kbyte/s)
Load subtitles in ./
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
Opening video filter: [screenshot]
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 54.33.100 (internal)
Selected video codec: [ffmpeg1] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg MPEG-1)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [mpg123] MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 224.0 kbit/15.87% (ratio: 28000->176400)
Selected audio codec: [mpg123] afm: mpg123 (MPEG 1.0/2.0/2.5 layers I, II, III)
==========================================================================
AO: [alsa] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
[VD_FFMPEG] Trying pixfmt=0.
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
[VD_FFMPEG] Trying pixfmt=1.
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
[VD_FFMPEG] Trying pixfmt=2.
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
The selected video_out device is incompatible with this codec.
Try appending the scale filter to your filter list,
e.g. -vf spp,scale instead of -vf spp.
Movie-Aspect is 1.33:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
[swscaler @ 0xfbf060]BICUBIC scaler, from yuv420p to rgb24 using MMX2
VO: [xv] 352x288 => 384x288 Planar YV12  [zoom]
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]ac-tex damaged at 12 3
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]concealing 330 DC, 330 AC, 330 MV errors
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]concealing 330 DC, 330 AC, 330 MV errors
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]concealing 330 DC, 330 AC, 330 MV errors
A:   3.7 V:   3.2 A-V:  0.530 ct: -0.038  26/ 26  1%  0%  0.5% 0 0 
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]slice mismatch
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]Warning MVs not available
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]concealing 330 DC, 330 AC, 330 MV errors
A:   3.7 V:   3.2 A-V:  0.526 ct: -0.034  27/ 27  1%  0%  0.5% 0 0 
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]concealing 330 DC, 330 AC, 330 MV errors
A:   3.8 V:   3.3 A-V:  0.482 ct: -0.030  28/ 28  1%  0%  0.5% 0 0 
[mpeg1video @ 0xef7180]concealing 330 DC, 330 AC, 330 MV errors
A:   3.8 V:   3.3 A-V:  0.478 ct: -0.026  29/ 29  1%  0%  0.5% 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, mplayer believes this to be mpeg1, which ffmpeg can handle just fine. Or at least, is supposed to be able to handle just fine, and normally mplayer prefers ffmpeg. You could attempt to force it to use a different decoder with `-vfm` or `-vc` options (pass "help" to either to get a list). You could also try a different `-demuxer` (also takes "help" for the list).

But I'm not sure that a 64-bit mplayer can load 32-bit codecs, anyway. There is a win64 codecs package you could try. Alternatively, you could install (possibly from source) a 32-bit mplayer.

Comment: And if the files aren't private, upload one for other people to try. A file that looks like plain mpeg but won't play in vanilla mplayer could be a bug that would be easy to fix when mplayer developers get their hands on the test case.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work with the `ia32-libs` package and a 32-bit version of `mplayer`.